# What is the simplest way to assign DNS name to EC2 instance using Route 53 service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have got a domain registered with GoDaddy and an EC2 instance with public elastic IP and I'm trying to use Amazon "Route 53" service to map the DNS name to my instance.
In online documentation there is a very complex example of using Perl (http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-Route-53?browse=1) to achieve this result.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 22):

The AWS team has meanwhile added complete support for [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) as of November 16, 2011, which allows you to *create your hosted zones and set up the appropriate records (A, CNAME, MX, and so forth) in a convenient visual environment.*

This is best experienced by exploring it yourself of course, but a sneak peak is available via  [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#rt53) and the introductory blog post [AWS Management Console Now Supports Amazon Route 53](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/11/aws-management-console-now-supports-amazon-route-53.html) provides a *walk through the entire process of registering a domain at a registrar and setting it up in Route 53*, including further illustrations.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there's no "Route 53" tab on AWS management console. But they've said that they'd be adding one in the future.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/12/amazon-route-53-the-aws-domain-name-service.html

So right now, the easiest way is to use third-party tools. Here's a list of tools that you can use:

- http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-Route-53/
- http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/new-location-for-route-53-and-cloudfront-route-53-tool-roundup.html
- https://github.com/rawswift/aws-sdk-for-php

I've also built a web-based interface for AWS Route 53. Has the basic features like creating/deleting hosted zones, adding/deleting A, AAAA, CNAME, PTR, SPF, SRV, TXT records and also supports multiple MX record value (e.g. Google MX records).

https://nsroute.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been pretty pleased using Interstate53:

```
 https://www.interstate53.com/
```

It offers a nice GUI for managing all of your Route 53 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are several web GUIs available for creating and modifying Route 53 zones and records including https://www.interstate53.com/

More options are listed in the documentation at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/GettingStartedGuide/

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links help you setup:

http://dmz.us/2010/12/amazon-route-53-dns/

Using Boto library:

http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2011/06/managing-amazon-route-53-dns-with-boto.html

This link, gives you a straight forward flow of configuring DNS to EC2 instance:

http://support.rightscale.com/03-Tutorials/02-AWS/02-Website_Edition/2._Deployment_Setup/4._Domain_Setup/Domain_Setup_with_Amazon's_Route_53